# non-linear inversion for up to 1E9 values in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Here is my problem. its very simple and I have already found some good approaches, but they are simply too slow:

I have a simple polynomial with order anywhere between 2 and 4 (this is a choice of the user). For now, lets just say we have 3rd order:

```
a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d = 0
```

I need to invert this function and get the (real) value of x, but for several million and even billion values. The coefficients (a, b, c) are always the same, but d is usually an array with several million entries.

e.g.

```
a = -0.001
b = -0.1
c = 1.5
d = numpy.random.rand(2000, 2000)
```

I was looking into the non linear solvers of scipy:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html

but this was just too slow. Is there any fast way to do the inversion?

I hope you understand my problem and thanks for any hint.
cheers

Comment: When the order is 2 or more, there can be more than one solution.  How do you want to handle multiple solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There exist analytic solutions: [Degree 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) and [Degree 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation). You could implement those directly.

**Update** (In reply to @HansSnah):

There is a general solution using [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org):

```
import sympy as sy

#sy.init_printing() # pretty printing for ipython console

a,b,c,d,e,x = sy.symbols("a,b,c,d,e,x", real=True)
eq3 = sy.Eq(a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d, 0)
eq3a = eq3.subs({a: -.011, b: 0.1, c: 1.5, d:0})
sy.solve(eq3a, x)
# Gives: [-7.98549886553656, 0.0, 17.0764079564457]
```

It just does not seem fast enough to me for 1e9 solutions either.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I realise, that there are analytic solutions with could be implemented, but I had hoped that there already is a package somewhere out there which does exactly this. 